# Smooth the join between 2 separate meshes

Tags: mesh

[image]

I have a body mesh where I separated the arms into another object to make UV mapping easier, but now the join between the torso and arms has this very noticeable line/bump.

Is there any way to smooth the gap? I would like to keep both the torso and arms as separate objects, but would also like to keep the cut between them smooth.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the only aim here is you find it easier for UV maps, merge them again once it is done. Considerer also that a separate arm will be very difficult to rig/weight paint with no effect or separation at this seam.

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve by separating the limbs from the body but IMHO there is no way to get rid of the line.

If you have two separate objects or even two sub-meshes that aren't connected, you will always have a visible line where they *seem* to be connected. This is just how shading in every renderer (at least the ones I know) works. And that's the reason why almost every 3D artist will keep limbs connected to the body.

Besides that your 3D Viewport is set "Solid" shading. In this mode your scene gets a basic material with basic lightning setup. That setup will make the line even more prominent compared to "Render View" with an actual light setup and a material applied. It might help a little, but you will never get rid of the line entirely.